# Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

MY MAIN CONTROLLER

```
var MyApp = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'MobiNav', 'authFactory']);
```

CONTROLLER CONSUMING FACTORY

```
MyApp.controller('AuthUser', ['$scope', 'authFactoryService', function ($scope, authFactoryService) {
    $scope.showForm = true;
    $scope.UserDataLogin = function () {
        var loginData = {};
        $scope.registration = {
            userName: $scope.Auth.userName,
            password: $scope.Auth.password,
            confirmPassword: $scope.Auth.password
        };
        authFactoryService.SaveRegistration(registration);
        window.scope = loginData;
    };
}
]
);
```

THIS IS THE FACTORY IN SEPERATE FILE

```
   var AuthService = angular.module('authFactory', []);
AuthService.factory('authFactoryService', [
    '$http', '$q', '$scope', function ($http, $q, $scope) {
    return {
        SaveRegistration: function() {
            var urlBase = 'http://localhost:48868/';
            $http.post(urlBase + 'api/account/register', registration).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.savedSuccessfully = true;
                    $scope.message = "User has been registered successfully, you will be redicted to login page in 2 seconds.";
                },
                function(response) {
                    var errors = [];
                    for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                            errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.message = "Failed to register user due to:" + errors.join(' ');
                });
        }

    };
}]);
```

error what i'm getting
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20authFactoryService
    at Error (native)

why it is unable to load **authFactoryService** service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Figured the dug,
**$scope** was again injected in Factory
replaced
this

```
AuthService.factory('authFactoryService', [
    '$http', '$q', '$scope', function ($http, $q, $scope) {}]);
```

to this (just removed the $scope which was again injected in factory for dependency.

```
   AuthService.factory('authFactoryService', [
        '$http', '$q', function ($http, $q, $scope) {}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> var AuthService = angular.module('authFactory', []);

You indlcuded the an empty array in your module. This makes it a
module setter, overwriting an existing module.
to fetch a module you use angular.module('authFactory') <-- note the missing second parameter.

Regards
Sander

Comment: i tried as above 
i'm getting below error message. Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/nomod?p0=authFactory